# CSS destroying display order

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm using VS2010,C# to develop my ASP.NET web app, I'm using a .js file to display some small tool tips in my program, there is a CSS file also that should be used in my ASPX files so that this tooltip is displayed correctly, but when I use this CSS all my page (including tables) are displayed at left side of page while I've aligned them to be at the center of page, I'm not an expert in CSS files, how can I fix this problem, here is my CSS file:

```
    * {margin:0; padding:0}
    body {font:12px/1.5 Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background:#FFF}
    #text {margin:50px auto; width:500px}
    .hotspot {color:#900; padding-bottom:1px; border-bottom:1px dotted #900; cursor:pointer}

    #tt {position:absolute; display:block; background:url(images/tt_left.gif) top left no-repeat}
    #tttop {display:block; height:5px; margin-left:5px; background:url(images/tt_top.gif) top right no-repeat; overflow:hidden}
    #ttcont {display:block; padding:2px 12px 3px 7px; margin-left:5px; background:#666; color:#FFF}
#ttbot {display:block; height:5px; margin-left:5px; background:url(images/tt_bottom.gif) top right no-repeat; overflow:hidden}
```

Comment: how are you centring your elements?

Comment: I'm using align="center", of course I set horizontalAlign property of tables in VS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#tt` is set to `position: absolute`. This is probably the cause of your problems since you are not telling it what position you want so I suspect it is defaulting to top left.

What CSS are you using to align things to the center? And what is your HTML structure? I am assuming that #tt is ta main container on your page...

To actually find out which part of your CSS is wrong though then the easiest way of doing it is to just remove each line/property from your CSS file and retest until the positioning stops dying.

Also if that CSS is there purely for your tooltip then you probably shouldn't be using a * selector. Something more specific like `.Tooltip *` would minimise any interference from anyting outside.

And in general if styles are meant to only apply to one given piece of content I would use a class (or id) on that content as a prefix to every selector to guarantee that you cannot possibly change anything outside of that.

Comment: I'm not using any kind of CSS, I just had to use this CSS to display my jscript tooltips, a part of my table in html:<asp:Table ID="tblPages" runat="server" Width="150px" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
            Font-Names="Tahoma" BackColor="#99FF99">

Answer (score 0):

Going on your code and comments, all I can see that would be effecting the layout of your page is that you are resetting all the margins and padding on your elements using the style

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
```

Also since you are not properly centring your elements (using a wrapping `<div>` with a fixed width and `margin: 0 auto;`, then it seems as though it is just your margins and padding that are now off.

Comment: thanks, I tried to remove the first line, but it didn't work, unfortunately I don't know so much about CSS, I'm more used to work with .NET server-side codes, of course positions are correct in IE but no luck in firefox! how can I fix it in all browsers?

Comment: to fix in all browser, get rid of `align="center"`, then add a `<div>` tag around the table or other elements which you want to center. so it would look a bit like `<div class="wrap"><table> or other elements you have</table></div>` then add a style in `div.wrap{ margin: 0 auto; width: 1000px }` replace the `1000px` with the width you desire.